# How can I \Aboxed a Matrix?

Tags: matrices, mathtools

I am trying to use `\Aboxed` around a function containing a `pmatrix`, but anything other than a column vector seems to break `\Aboxed`.  I think it has something to do with the `&`'s in the matrix, but I am not sure.  `\boxed` seems to work fine when wrapped around a matrix, but that forces me out of the `align` enviroment.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, but the aboxed code is what is triggering the error if you try to compile it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{cancel}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \boxed{ \rho^{(z)}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1   &   0   \\
            0   &   0
        \end{pmatrix}}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{align}
        \Aboxed{    \rho^{(z)}
        &=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1   &   0   \\
            0   &   0
        \end{pmatrix}}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Enclose the `pmatrix` in the `\Aboxed` version in a pair of braces `{ }`. The `\Aboxed` macro works by scanning its argument for `&`, the `{ }` hide those from it.

Comment: How do I promote this to an answer!  Worked perfectly!

Comment: You can ping the user by placing an `\@` char asking to convert it to an answer @Qrrbrbirlbel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to enclose the `pmatrix` environment in a pair of braces `{ }`

The internal version of `\Aboxed`, `\@Aboxed`, uses `&` to split its argument. Normally, this just strips everything after a possible second `&`, as in the second example below.
In this case though, you’re splitting the `pmatrix` environment which would create a sequence of math-mode commands similar to the (commented) third example.

The additional `{ }` hide these `&` from the `\@Aboxed` macro.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \Aboxed{\rho^{(z)}
        &=
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            1   &   0   \\
            0   &   0
        \end{pmatrix}}} \\
        %
        \Aboxed{\rho^z & = \rho^z & a & = b}
        %
%        \\ \rho^z & = \begin{pmatrix} 1 % <- not a good idea
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I've added your solution as a comment in the mathtools manual for the next release.